# Connecting arrow shape in to a String

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

Is it possible to create an up/down arrow shape, connect it to a String and then show it on a control?

I am trying to simulate up/down stocks quotes with arrows which tell if the stock is rising or declining.

Thanks.

Comment: You can put images on buttons, which would probably be your best bet in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ↑ and ↓ in string for your purpose. Ref: [UPARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm) & [DOWNARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2193/index.htm)

```
   String str = "MSFT (26.00) ↓)";
   Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Thanks. how do i draw this up and down arrow? using ASCI? in this case if you can tell me the values of the ASCI...

Comment: See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2193/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could look in the various [Unicode charts](http://unicode.org/charts) for a suitable character - although you'd then have to make sure that it was supported by the font you're using. [This chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2B00.pdf) of miscellaneous symbols and arrows would probably be a good starting point.

I suspect using an image would be a better bet though.